# Auto decimal round at the moment of the insertion into the database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, decimal, entity-framework-5

I have an entity E with an attribute decimal value

When I insert this entity into the database the value is automatically round to only 2 numbers after the , (only inside the database my entity keep the full precision value but inside the database and wherever it is declared decimal(18 8) it rounds to 2 after the ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the documentation for `DbModelBuilder`, you can set the precision of decimals using `HasPrecision`. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.decimalpropertyconfiguration.hasprecision(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: Yes that's it
In my EntityTypeConfiguration class for E I added this line and it works
this.Property(t => t.value).HasColumnName("value").HasPrecision(18, 8)